# getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Tags: java, servlets, requestdispatcher

> getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

this error comes in line where I have forwarded the response to some other page..

```
rd.forward(req,res);
```

Comment: Fill up proper details while asking questions. Paste your error or exception.

Comment: Show the complete stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments:

> *no it is simply jsp/servlet and using the same I download csv file*

It sounds like as if you're trying to forward the response *after* sending the CSV file to the response. That is not possible. You cannot send two different responses to a single request. When you're finished with sending the CSV, you should stop touching the request/response. It has already done its job and you should wait on the next request.

If your *actual* intent is to change the parent page after your download the CSV, then it has to be solved differently, but that would require JavaScript code.